# Is there any way for Retrieve Record Value from Table Column , Loop and Loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, runnable, records

*Sorry for my poor English*

1. When the user clicks the Start button, I am trying to display all of the records from the `Phone` column in the `Textbox1` control.  I want to see all those records pass into `Textbox1` While it is processing the `For` loop.  But it is currently processing very fast so that I only see the last record in `Textbox1`.  What i'm going wrong?
2. While it is processing the `For` loop, I change the Start button to a Stop button.  So when I click the button and it currently has a `Text` value equal to `"Stop"`, I want it to skip the `For` loop and pass the value from `TextBox1` to my `FirstWin`.  And then it should change the `BtnStart.Text` back to `"Start"`

Here's my code:

```
Public Class PhoneFortune
    Dim CN As OleDbConnection
    Dim CM As OleDbCommand
    Dim DA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Private Sub BtnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStart.Click
        If BtnStart.Text = "Start" Then
            CM = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TblPhoneNumber", CN)
            DA = New OleDbDataAdapter(CM)
            DA.Fill(DT)
            For i = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
                TextBox1.Text = DT.Rows(i)("Phone")
            Next
            BtnStart.Text = "Stop"
        End If
        If BtnStart.Text = "Stop" Then
            If FirstWin.Text = "" Then
                FirstWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                BtnStart.Text = "Start"
            ElseIf SecondWin.Text = "" Then
                SecondWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                BtnStart.Text = "Start"
            ElseIf ThirdWin.Text = "" Then
                ThirdWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                BtnStart.Text = "Start"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PhoneFortune_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CN = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=database\db.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=12345;")
        CN.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want this to do.  Are you saying you want to intentionally slow it down so that it will take longer than it otherwise should to complete the loop?  Do you really intend to make this multi-threaded (as your tag implies)?  If so, it's not currently multi-threaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

I hope we are on the same page but if u want to slow down the process for a bit u use these two lines of code within the FOR loop
 
        `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`
        `Me.Refresh()` Where 1000 is one second(value is represented in milliseconds).

Now what is that `FirstWin.Text=""` etc used for? Are you trying to start the looping,then change the text to "stop" so that when the user clicks stops it stops at the current record? Go to youtube and look for multithreading videos,not sure how to help u on that one hope the rest helps. If this is useful please acknowledge

Comment: The user will still be unable to click the stop button because the UI thread will still be stuck in the `For` loop.

Comment: well multi threading is the answer but im not familiar with how to code it

Comment: It worked. 
But I got the Error When i close form.
Because the thread is still running.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            If Button1.Text = "Start" Then
                If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                    t1 = New Thread(AddressOf Me.PhoneThread)
                    t1.Start()
                    Button1.Text = "Stop"
                Else
                    t1.Resume()
                    Button1.Text = "Stop"
                End If
            Else    'Click Stop
                t1.Suspend()
                Button1.Text = "Start"
                If FirstWin.Text = "" Then
                    FirstWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                ElseIf SecondWin.Text = "" Then
                    SecondWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                ElseIf ThirdWin.Text = "" Then
                    ThirdWin.Text = TextBox1.Text
                End If


            End If
        End Sub
        Sub PhoneThread()
            'Dim ThreadsArray As List(Of Threading.Thread) = New List(Of Threading.Thread)
            Dim s As Integer
            'MsgBox(DT.Rows.Count)
            For s = 0 To DT.Rows.Count
                If s = DT.Rows.Count Then
                    s = 0
                Else
                    TextBox1.Text = DT.Rows(s)("Phone")
                    '   ThreadsArray.Add(t1)
                    Thread.Sleep(19)
                    'TextBox1.Text = s.ToString()
                    Me.Refresh()
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
 Private Sub BtnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStart.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like this, `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` (to block the thread) followed by `Application.DoEvents()` (to process any button clicks) seems like it would do the trick.

For something more complicated, this approach will result in re-entrancy and difficult-to-reproduce bugs; in that case, you definitely need [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).